# Importing certain cell range from a wiki page

Tags: wikipedia

I need help importing just the symbols of the Dow from this page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average

I can get the full table just using the following, but can't figure out how to just get the symbols and only the symbols listed on that page.
=importhtml("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average","table")

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=index(importhtml("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average","table"),,4)
```